# Problems on Unit conversion

Tags: android

I developed a simple Unit converter, and I am stuck on 2 problems.
First one is after I compile and run APK, application crashes on click of convert button.
Second one is I don't know how I can connect forResult(variable for answer after calculation) to box next to Text "After". 
I really beg for your help.... Thanks....^^

```
Main.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="left|right"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="#66FFFF" >    

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" >
</FrameLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/UnitText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/UnitText"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/Spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:prompt="@string/UnitPrompt"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp" >
</FrameLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:onClick="converter"
        android:id="@+id/ConvertButton"
        android:layout_width="131dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ConvertText" />

</LinearLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dip" >
</FrameLayout>

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/BeforeBox"
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/BeforeText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/BeforeText"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/AfterBox"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/AfterText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/AfterText"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

```
BasicUnitconverterActivity.Java

package arirang.unit.converter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
public class BasicUnitConverterActivity extends Activity {

private double val1;
Spinner Type;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.UnitList, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
}   



public void converter() {
    Type = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.Spinner1);
    val1 = (R.id.BeforeBox);
    double dbResult = 0;

    if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("meter to inch"))
    {
        dbResult = val1 * 39.3700787 ;
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("meter to feet"))
    {
        dbResult = val1 * 3.2808399;
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("feet to inch"))
    {
        dbResult = val1 * 12;
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("feet to meter"))
    {
        dbResult = val1 / 3.2808399;
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("inch to meter"))
    {
        dbResult = val1 / 39.3700787 ;
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("inch to feet"))
    {
        dbResult = val1 / 12;
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("kilogram to pound"))
    {
        dbResult = val1 * 2.20462262;
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("pound to kilogram"))
    {
        dbResult = val1 / 2.20462262;
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Fahernheit to Celsius"))
    {
        dbResult=(val1 - 32) / (5 / 9);
    }

    else if(Type.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Celsius to Fahernheit"))
    {
        dbResult = (9 / 5) * val1 + 32;
    }

    TextView ShowBox = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.AfterBox);
    ShowBox.setText("forResult");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of important pieces of information that you left out. One is the logcat information of the crash. The other is the onClick method when the Convert button is clicked.

I have one suggestion for you. If that doesn't help then please post more information.

I'm going to assume that clicking the Convert button ends up calling the converter method you have listed. In that method you have the following:

```
val1 = (R.id.BeforeBox);
```

You then use val1 in subsequent calculations. This line of code will get you the ID of the BeforeBox, not the contents of that EditText. I'm not sure if this would be enough to cause the crash or whether it would just give you strange results.

Comment: I used android:onClick="converter"... but what command or code I need to use to get number from BeforeBox to val1???

Comment: BeforeBox is an EditText so you start with something like EditText t = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.BeforeBox); Then you can retrieve the text with String s = t.getText().toString(); Then you can do something like Double d(s); and finally val1=s.doubleValue(); -- sorry about the formatting here but I can't insert a line feed in this comment box.